# Pressed button in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I find some code that can help me to create a button which can be animated when it pressed. But it is on objective-c. Generally i can understand about what this code, but i can't correctly translate it on swift. Please help me translate it on swift. Thanks a lot.

1.

```
- (SKSpriteNode *)fireButtonNode
{
    SKSpriteNode *fireNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"fireButton.png"];
    fireNode.position = CGPointMake(fireButtonX,fireButtonY);
    fireNode.name = @"fireButtonNode";
    fireNode.zPosition = 1.0;
    return fireNode;
}
```

2.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"fireButtonNode"]) {
    }
}
```

Comment: @Mr.Tigr Oh, and I agree in general with what IInspectable said. I've made an example for you because  it doesn't require much time and especially because I've noticed that you are a new member, but it is always better idea to include what you have tried so far to show the effort in solving the issue. That way, you are not risking of being downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift:

```
func getFireButtonNode()->SKSpriteNode{

        let fireButtonX = CGRectGetMidX(frame), fireButtonY = CGRectGetMidY(frame)

        let fireNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "fireButton")
        fireNode.position = CGPoint(x: fireButtonX, y: fireButtonY)
        fireNode.name = "fireButtonNode"
        fireNode.zPosition = 1.0

        return fireNode

    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        if let touch = touches.first {


            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            let node = nodeAtPoint(location )

            if node.name == "fireButtonNode" {
                //do your stuff here
            }
        }

    }
```

Note that variables `fireButtonX` and `fireButtonY` are never initialized in your code example. You can define them in `getFireButtonNode`, like I did, or you can pass them as arguments when calling `getFireButtonNode` method, like this:

```
 func getFireButtonNode(xPos:CGFloat, _ yPos:CGFloat)->SKSpriteNode{}
```

And call it like this:

```
getFireButtonNode(100,100)
```

If you want to call it like this:

```
getFireButtonNode(xPos:100, yPos:100)
```

you will have to define an external and local parameter names explicitly, like this:

```
func getFireButtonNode(xPos x:CGFloat, yPos y:CGFloat)->SKSpriteNode{}
```

where xPos (as well as yPos) is an external parameter name and it will be used as an argument name when you are calling the function. x and y are local parameters, and you use them inside of functions body.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at apples demo project "DemoBots"? They have a helper for buttons.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DemoBots/Listings/DemoBots_Nodes_ButtonNode_swift.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015179-DemoBots_Nodes_ButtonNode_swift-DontLinkElementID_62

another simpler example

http://nathandemick.com/programming/tutorial/2014/09/23/buttons-sprite-kit-using-swift.html

and finally a gitHub project.

https://github.com/nguyenpham/sgbutton

In my personal games I use apples demo bot example with some tweaks that are relevant for me. This class also helps for tvOs focus stuff.